# Windows cannot be installed to this disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, bios, windows-8.1

I ran into a problem today. I have a HP pavillion dm4 laptop and it was running windows 7. I wanted to install windows 8.1 and used a bootable usb drive. I did custom install and formatted and deleted one partition. But unfortunately the drive was Dynamic and every other partitions were merged into single one. This not the problem coz I think I can recover the data and I have most important data backuped. The problem is that the OS cannot be installed. It shows the following error message:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may
>   not support booting to this disk. Ensure the disk's controller is
>   enabled in the computer's BIOS menu.

I searched for the problem and were some suggestions like setting on the AHCI mode on BIOS. But there is no option for SATA mode in my BIOS configuration. I am in deep trouble.
 Please help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: So you only have a single disk, and you've blown away all partitions? Are you sure you're not picking the USB drive you're trying to install from? :)

Comment: @techie007 No the size is showing about 500 GB. This is where I want to install. The USB drive has only 8 GB space.

Comment: @Ramhound It's HP Pavilion dm4-1160us

Comment: I solved this problem but don't know the reason behind it.
I **clean installed Windows 7** and I created partitions during installation. The installation was successful.
After the installation I again tried to **install Windows 8.1** and this time there was no such error message. It was also a clean installation process.
The installation was successful.
What was happening previously? Any Reasons?

Comment: There just isn't enough detail on what you did and what the partition's state were.  Too many possibilities, and since the problem went away, not much we can do about it to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer on the following question ["Computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk" when trying to install Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1074592/computers-hardware-may-not-support-booting-to-this-disk-when-trying-to-instal)

> I encountered this problem once when installing windows 10 on ASUS
>   Transformer Book Flip TP200SA. I solved the problem by changing the
>   USB mode from auto to forced fdd. That may solve your problem too.

i hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I got same problem on ASUS TP200SA and finally found a solution.

I had to create boot USB with "GPT for UEFI" instead of old regular "MBR for BIOS or UEFI", so BIOS loaded it not in legacy mode, but in UEFI, then just deleted partition, pressed Next on allocated space and thats it!

Looks like the problem is that BIOS in legacy mode can't create boot record on NVMe SSD

Comment: I don't see any reference in the question to an NVMe SSD.

Comment: Asus tp200sa has such by default, and looks like this is common issue for this model