# Windows Cannot Be Installed to This Disk (Old BIOS System)

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, bios

I replaced my computer's old HDD with a SSD and am getting the error when trying to reinstall Windows 10 from a USB drive:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The computers hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS.

I found some other posts on SuperUser about this (["Computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk" when trying to install Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1074592/computers-hardware-may-not-support-booting-to-this-disk-when-trying-to-instal), for example), but the answers there seem to be focused on EFI-based systems. I've tried to redo the partitions, using both Windows' command line tools and, alternately, GParted on Ubuntu to no avail.

Ubuntu installed and booted just fine on that disk. Is there some way to turn off Windows' BIOS check so that it will just install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk" when trying to install Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1074592/computers-hardware-may-not-support-booting-to-this-disk-when-trying-to-instal)

Comment: I actually cite that question in my post. It seems to be focused on using a UEFI system rather than BIOS-based one, so some of the suggestions provided do not apply.

Comment: A possible work-around: image the HDD to the SSD using software such as Macrium Reflect, and set the SSD as bootable.

Comment: You don't mention if this SSD is SATA, PCIe, or NVMe.  Some older chipsets are physical unable to boot from NVMe based SSDs.  Meanwhile, NVMe also requires UEFI compatability, Windows and Linux UEFI/BIOS compatability is handled different and cannot be compared.  If you are getting this message, I can almost guarantee you, its due to UEFI/GPT and your installation environment being in Legacy mode (or vice versa).  Widows cannot be installed on GPT while booted in Legacy mode, likewise, Windows cannot be installed on MBR while booted in UEFI mode.  This limitation cannot be be overcome.

Comment: Are you trying to install 64-bit Windows to a 32-bit computer? Is your disk MBR or GPT? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)