# Lenovo T460s will see HD in BIOS but will not boot to it

Tags: windows-10, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T460s that will show the internal HD in the BIOS and the startup selection menu, but when I attempt to boot to it, it just flashes a black screen and returns to the setup menu.

It would appear that the BIOS isn't allowing the HD to boot, right?

- I changed UEFI --> Legacy and vice versa.
- I made sure Secure Boot is off
- I made sure CMS was set to 'Yes' on Legacy
- I reset the BIOS via 'Load Setup Defaults' in the Restart section of
  the BIOS

I attempted to reinstall Windows 10 from an ISO and after deleting all partitions in the Advanced (custom) settings I got this error: "Windows Cannot Be Installed to This Disk. This Computer's Hardware May not Support Booting to This Disk".

Lenovo ThinkPad does not seem to have an Advanced settings or any way to change the SATA controller mode. My company has purchased about 300 of these and a handful of them seem to be having this exact issue. I'm at a loss for what may be happening.

Any other ideas?
Thanks!

EDIT: I replaced the hard drive with a known good hard drive and the issue is still unresolved. Likewise, I placed the problematic machine's hard drive into another T460s and it worked fine. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk" when trying to install Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1074592/computers-hardware-may-not-support-booting-to-this-disk-when-trying-to-instal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common demononator ended up being compatibility related to the form factor of the M.2 hard drives. It only worked with M.2 SATA SSD drives and not M2 NVMe SSD drives because every M.2 SATA drive worked and every M.2 NVMe drive did not. As I said in my post, my company purchased about 300 of these from a vendor and they appear to have a variety of M.2 hard drives installed.

[Here is a photo of the two drives side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OMpK.jpg)

The drive on the right worked every time (SATA) and the drive on the left was exhibiting the original issue. It seems that this type of SSD drive is not compatible with the Lenovo Motherboard on the T460s.

Answer (score 0):

Since the computer will not start and is likely a defective disk drive (based on your post), you will need to test the drive with a bootable USB Key. Try hddscan.

https://hddscan.com/

Also you can put the drive in a carrier and put it in another computer and test it with CHKDSK run from the good computer.

If the Drive proves good, you need to ensure it is compatible with your system, and then BIOS may need updating.

Go here:

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t460s/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI

Get the Bootable CD for BIOS update and update the BIOS.

Make sure in BIOS that you reset BIOS to default settings.

If updating BIOS fails, then the machine will need hardware service from Lenovo.

Comment: I replaced the hd with a known good one and it did not resolve the issue. Likewise, I put the problematic machine's hard drive into another T460s and it worked fine.. It still seems to be something within the BIOS.

Comment: Thank you.  I amended my answer to include updating BIOS and the possibility of Service.